# Tweet search by combined key work with tweepy API

Tags: search, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to search tweets with combined word like "Delta Airlines"

```
new_tweets = api.search(q="Delta flight", count=tweetsPerQry,
                                        max_id=str(max_id - 1))
```

If I search for a combined word like 
`q="Delta flight"`, I find tweets but they don't contain  "Delta flight" together.

This is what I got:

> @**Delta** free idea. For valued customers how about a text message for when the **flight** is about to board.

This is what I'd expect to get (and what I do get when I search Twitter itself)

> Apparently someone's phone battery (not sure which kind yet) just exploded on my **Delta flight** 2557 o.O Seems like everyone's alright, though

> That's a new one: A **Delta flight** attendant just implored everyone not to use their Samsung Galaxy Note 7s in flight

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're searching for `"Delta Airlines"`, why are you expecting to get stuff containing "Delta flight"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: you just have to escape the quotation marks: **q="\"delta flight\""** will return what you want.

Solution 2: filter the tweets afterwards, with something along the lines of **if "delta flight" in tweet.text.lower():**.